# git-completion.bash displays HEAD only

Tags: git, bash, shell

I put original git-completion.bash (from git tarball) and source it from my ~/bash_profile.

When using git branch  is shows only HEAD, e.g.:

```
piotr@PiotrMBP ~/Projects/X  (master) 
$ git co HEAD
```

but I have:

```
$ git br -a
  NSXMLDocument
* master
  origin/HEAD
  origin/NSXMLDocument
  origin/master
```

I haven't modified git-completion.bash in any way, and it works as you can see, while I have branch name in my PS, like in line:
piotr@PiotrMBP ~/Projects/X  (master)

Where should I look for any clues on why branches are not displayed as expected?

Comment: What version of Git are you using? Git1.6.3.1 from May 2009 did enhance branch display: http://osdir.com/ml/git/2009-05/msg01716.html

Comment: I feel stupid, installing git version 1.6.4.4 solved the problem, thanks for thesuggestion, VonC!

Comment: Alright :) Just added this comment as an answer, for other readers having the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, the version of Git matters here.

Git1.6.3.1 did enhance branch display for instance ([May 2009](http://osdir.com/ml/git/2009-05/msg01716.html))